# jQuery Input Mask Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput, input-mask

I am trying to set up a donations page for people to give money to a non-profit and allow them to specify the uses of the money.  I have it set up that it totals the amounts the giver puts in each field as they enter amounts.  I am trying to add an input mask in each field, but it is just making my JavaScript crash and not do anything.  Here is the code I currently have that works perfectly before any masks:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        var calcTot = function() {
            var sum = 0;
            $('.toTotal').each( function(){
                sum += Number( $(this).val() );
                });
            $('#giveTotal').val( '$' + sum.toFixed(2) );
        }

        calcTot();

        $('.toTotal').change( function(){
            calcTot();
            });
        });
</script>
```

'toTotal' is the class name given to all the input boxes that need to be added up; that is also the class that needs a mask.  'giveTotal' is the id of the total field.

I have tried several variations I have found on StackOverflow and other sites.

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function() {

            //This is one of the masking codes I attempted.
            $('.toTotal').mask('9.99', {reverse: true});

            //other options I have tried:
            //$('.toTotal').mask('9.99');
            //$('.toTotal').mask('0.00');
            //$('.toTotal').inputmask('9.99');
            //$('.toTotal').inputmask('mask', {'mask': '9.99'});

            var calcTot = function() {
                var sum = 0;
                $('.toTotal').each( function(){
                    sum += Number( $(this).val() );
                    });
                $('#giveTotal').val( '$' + sum.toFixed(2) );
            }
            calcTot();

            $('.toTotal').change( function(){
                calcTot();
                });

            //I have tried putting it here, too

            });
    </script>

    <title>Addition</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" class="toTotal"><br />
<input type="text" class="toTotal"><br />
<input type="text" class="toTotal"><br />
<input type="text" id="giveTotal">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the mask code that is causing the error?

Comment: As I said I tried lots of varieties.  The one I hoped would work was `$('.toTotal').mask('000,000.00', {reverse: true});`.  I also tried variations I found that used `.inputmask`, with and without `{reverse: true}`, and 9s instead of 0s.  I don't know if placement might have been an issue as well.  My first option was to put this code on the line before `var calcTot = function() {`.  I also tryied it at the end of ready function and in the middle of it.

Comment: Can you provide a full code sample in the question as it's not possible to answer without seeing a specific problem. The only solution I can think of without seeing this is that the Mask Plugin scripts weren't being included.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no masking library script referenced in the sample code. You need to download the [Digital Bush Masked Input Plugin Script](https://raw.github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/1.3.1/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js) and copy it into your JS folder.

Then add following script reference after 'jquery.js' line:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I knew it had to be something incredibly small that I was missing.